# Can't store all data from NSArray into NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

What's the problem with this code?? I am trying to put the data from an NSArray to a NSMutableDictionary but I do not want to first split the initial nsarray into two and then send the data to the nsdcitionary.

The problem is that when I NSLog de mutabledictionary it returns me just the 1 item which happens to be the last data from the NSArray.

```
 NSString *str = @"13:00,2.00,13:05,2.03,13:10,2.07,13:15,2.01,13:20,2.08,13:25,2.10,13:30,2.15";
NSArray *arrayFinal = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayFinal count ]; i = i + 2) {
    [dict setObject:[arrayFinal objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"hora"];
    [dict setObject:[arrayFinal objectAtIndex:i+1] forKey:@"preco"];

}
```

The result is:

```
2013-09-04 20:27:33.732 separa[1438:c07] {
hora = "13:30";
preco = "2.15";
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense. You are trying to reuse the same keys over and over. What is your goal? Do you actually want an array of dictionaries?

Comment: I wanna take the data from the array into the dictionary. The dictionary should have to keys: 'hora' and 'preco'. hora would store the hours in the array and preco would store the price in the array.

Comment: So either you have a dictionary of arrays or an array of dictionaries, you choose.

Comment: So you want the "hora" key to point to an array of hours, correct?

Comment: Yes rmaddy. Each hour stored in the array should be in the dictionary attached to the 'hora' key. and so for the price.

Comment: So use "hora" as the key and "preco" as the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayFinal count ]; i = i + 2) {
    [dict setObject:[arrayFinal objectAtIndex:i+1] forKey:[arrayFinal objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: PERFECT Hot Licks!!!! This was EXACTLY what I wanted!!!!!

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida man, you should express yourself better. This is not what you told rmaddy. You said you wanted hora to be the key, now the keys are the actual values of hora not the string @"hora".

Comment: @JuanCatalan - Sometimes, in the real world, you've got to look beyond the "specifications" to see what makes sense.

Comment: @HotLicks Agreed but what others answered makes as much sense (if not more) than this answer (based on question and posted code). And just because the OP asked a poorly worded question is no reason for the other answers to be downvoted.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree you gave the answer that makes more sense, but OP answered to a question of rmaddy with different requirements, that is why he posted a different answer, trying to fulfill OP requirements. Not trying to give a better answer. However it is nice to have diversity of opinions in this community.

Comment: @JuanCatalan well maybe you're right and if rmaddy got bored, please excuse me, but BOTH answers solved the problem, and Hot Licks', as I said, was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You should modify the original question to reflect what you were looking for. So instead of dict[@"hora"] you wanted dict[@"13:00"], dict[@"13:05"], etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need each key to point to an array of values. Something like this:

```
NSString *str = @"13:00,2.00,13:05,2.03,13:10,2.07,13:15,2.01,13:20,2.08,13:25,2.10,13:30,2.15";
NSArray *arrayFinal = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSMutableArray *horas = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *precos = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayFinal count]; i += 2) {
    [horas addObject:arrayFinal[i]];
    [precos addObject:arrayFinal[i + 1]];
}

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
dict[@"hora"] = horas;
dict[@"preco"] = precos;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to separate the two (hours and prices) into their own NSMutableArrays, then store each array as one of the keys, something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *hora = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *preco = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *str = @"13:00,2.00,13:05,2.03,13:10,2.07,13:15,2.01,13:20,2.08,13:25,2.10,13:30,2.15";
NSArray *arrayFinal = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayFinal count ]; i = i + 2) 
{
    [hora addObject:[arrayFinal objectAtIndex:i];
    [preco addObject:[arrayFinal objectAtIndex:i+1];
}

[dict setObject:hora forKey:@"hora"];
[dict setObject:preco forKey:@"preco"];
```

Probably not exactly the way I'd do it, but I think it is the concept you're looking for.

Comment: Do you realize that you duplicated my answer?

Comment: And how would you do RegularExpression?

Comment: Sorry, rmaddy.  You posted your while I was typing mine.  I don't have thing about points, so Marco should just accept yours.